# How to use R-exams package to create a multi-part question?

Tags: r-exams

Suppose I had an exam question such as "A car starting from rest accelerates to 26.82 m/s in 3.2 s. Compute the acceleration during this time. How far did the car travel in this time?"

I'm new to R-exams package. In the past I've used MIT's "exam" LaTex package. There, I'd do something like:

```
\begin{question}
A car starting from rest accelerates to 26.82 m/s in 3.2 s.
\begin{parts}
\part Compute the acceleration during this time.
\part How far did the car travel in this time?
\end{parts}
```

I've poked around the r-exams.org but don't see any examples of creating such a multipart question.

Answer (score 1):

For combining multiple questions in a single exercise you can use the "cloze" type: http://www.R-exams.org/intro/dynamic/. Some concrete examples are linked from there.

In your case, if you want to use R/LaTeX markup (.Rnw) in the exercise, the question would become:

```
\begin{question}
A car starting from rest accelerates to 26.82 m/s in 3.2 s.
\begin{answerlist}
\item Compute the acceleration during this time.
\item How far did the car travel in this time?
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}
```

The corresponding meta-information needs to include something like:

```
\extype{cloze}
\exclozetype{num|num}
\exsolution{8.38125|42.912}
```

R/Markdown (.Rmd) would, of course, be possible as well. And both are hopefully straightforward to turn into dynamic exercises where the numbers are sampled randomly. Let us know if you need further help with this.

Comment: This was very helpful. My first "cloze" question. However, when I use exams2nops function I get this error: "the following exercises are cloze exercises: ..." If I use exams2pdf it works fine, except the solutions are printed as well which doesn't work well if I plan to issue the exam to students.

Comment: In `exams2nops()` there is no support for cloze questions but you can see this discussion: <https://R-Forge.R-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=33878&forum_id=4377&group_id=1337>. In `exams2pdf()` you have to use a `template=` that gives the layout you want. As a first step `exams2pdf(..., template = "exam")` might be useful.